# CSS: How to make background of an element stretch across the entire page?

Tags: html, css, background

I'm starting to learn CSS and really don't know how to deal with this problem. I am trying to make a solid colored top bar similiar to the black bar on bottom of this page. However when I try to do it, the color sort of makes a box around the text, instead of going from the borders of the page. I tried playing around with width/height with no success.

Thanks

EDIT:

```css
 body { margin:0;}
.
.
.
#bar{
      height: 100%; //these dont do anything
      width: 100%;
   background-color:black;}
```

```html
<div id=bar>       <h1> <a href="index.html"> <span id=stuff>stuff </span></a>
       <br> <span id=stuff> stuff stuff stuff</span> </h1> 

       <ul>
<li><a href="#stuff">stuff stuff stuff</a></li>
<li><a href="#stuff">stuff stuff stuff</a></li>
<li><a href="#stuff">stuff stuff stuff</a></li>
<li><a href="#stuff">stuff stuff stuff</a></li>
<li><a href="#stuff">stuff stuff stuff</a></li>
<li><a href="#stuff">stuff stuff stuff</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML and CSS codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browsers set default margins, you can override them including `body { margin:0; }` in your CSS.

UPDATE: you've got h1 there, it also has its own margins, so add `h1 {margin:0;}` as well.

```css
body { margin: 0 }

#topBar { background: black; color: white; }
```

```html
<div id=topBar>Top bar</div>
```

Comment: This sorta worked, because the bar is now horizontally fully stretched, but there is still white bar above it.

Comment: @mandatory if you include your HTML and CSS it will be easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried a width and height of 100% on de background image?

Answer (score 0):

1) You should set `width: 100%;` on the element and make sure all parent elements have that too. In this way the element is told to stretch out to the full width of the page. [You did this propably already :) ]

2) Also, make sure that the element is a block element or inline-block element (with `display: inline-block`), so it doesn't act as a normal inline element (which will be as big as its contents needs).

Comment: I tried display: inline-block and background vanished completly.